# Window built with qt designer not showing up

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I'm trying to learn how to build some simple gui stuff with pyqt, and i made a dialog window with a label, line edit and pushbutton in Qt designer and converted the ui file to python code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'gui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(569, 444)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 90, 46, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 90, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 160, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.lineEdit.clear)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "TextLabel", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton", None))
```

And here's the code from the file that imports the gui file

```
import sys
from gui import *
class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
if __name__ == "main":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When i try running it with python.exe window pops up for split-second and disappears. I'm using python 3.4 and Qt 4.1.1.4 32 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the miss-spelling of `'main'` in your code, it should be:

`if __name__ == "__main__":  #main with two underscores on both sides`

Comment: *facepalms* Can't belive i did that. Thanks